# Change AWS's full screen "menu" output to just standard out?

Tags: aws-cli

Is there a way to turn off the default "full screen output" that requires you to press Q to end? For example, if I run the following command:

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information
```

It's almost equivalent to typing `less <file>` where I have to hit Q to get out of the output, and I have the ability to scroll up and down.

I saw that the documentation mentioned that the `--output text` option could be used to pipe into other tools, but it's still not just spitting out the output. It's still putting me in this output "menu" where I have to hit Q to output.

How do I accomplish this so that these `aws` commands can just simply output the text the same way as running `ifconfig`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it's because AWS CLI version 2 uses the default pager program, which is `less`. After adding this to my `~/.aws/config` file, I was able to get what I needed:

```
cli_pager=
```

Comment: This doesn't work for help commands like `aws ecs help`, as it's [explained on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6843#issuecomment-1088170419).